# C++ user-defined conversion operators without classes?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, coercion

In C++ is it possible to define conversion operators which are not class members? I know how to do that for regular operators (such as +), but not for conversion operators.

Here is my use case: I work with a C Library which hands me out a `PA_Unichar *`, where the library defines PA_Unichar to be a 16-bit int. It is actually a string coded in UTF-16. I want to convert it to a `std::string` coded in UTF-8. I have all the conversion code ready and working, and I am only missing the syntactic sugar that would allow me to write:

```
PA_Unichar *libOutput = theLibraryFunction();
std::string myString = libOutput;
```

(usually in one line without the temp variable).

Also worth noting:

- I know that `std::string` doesn't define implicit conversion from `char*` and I know why. The same reason might apply here, but that's beside the point.
- I do have a `ustring`, subclass of `std::string` that defines the right conversion operator from `PA_Unichar*`. It works but this means using `ustring` variables instead of `std::string` and that *then* requires conversion to `std::string` when I use those strings with other libraries. So that doesn't help very much.
- Using an assignment operator doesn't work as those **must** be class members.

So is it possible to define implicit conversion operators between two types you don't control (in my case `PA_Unichar*` and `std::string`), which may or may not be class types?

If not what could be workarounds?

Answer (score 9):

What's wrong with a free function?

```
std::string convert(PA_Unichar *libOutput);

std::string myString = convert(theLibraryFunction());
```

*Edit* answering to the comment:

As [DrPizza says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618039/1618830#1618830): Everybody else is trying to plug the holes opened up by implicit conversions through replacing them with those explicit conversion which you call "visual clutter".

As to the temporary string: Just wait for the next compiler version. It's likely to come with rvalue references and its `std::string` implementation will implement move semantics on top of that, which eliminates the copy. I have yet to see a cheaper way to speedup your code than than by simply upgrading to a new compiler version.

Comment: what's wrong? Not much, but still, two things:  

- the visual clutter, when you have hundreds of meaningless calls to convert  

- this solutions implies the use of a temporary std::string. This means the data is copied twice, all the time. This may or may not be a problem, but is not very satisfying.

Comment: Most compilers will optimize the extra copy out.

Comment: jdmuys> rlbond is right, RVO is common and real in practice. You might wand to read that : http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can define "global" conversion operators. The standards say that `conversion functions` are `special member functions`. I would propse the following if I could consider the following syntax sugar:

```
struct mystring : public string
{
    mystring(PA_Unichar * utf16_string)
    {
        // All string functionality is present in your mystring.
        // All what you have to do is to write the conversion process.
        string::operator=("Hello World!");
        string::push_back('!');
        // any string operation...
    }
};
```

Be aware that polymorphic behavior of this class is broken. As long as you don't create an object of it through a pointer of type `string*` though, you are in the safe-side! So, this code is perfect:

```
mystring str(....);
```

As said before, the following code is broken!

```
string* str = new mystring(....);
....
delete str; // only deleting "string", but not "mystring" part of the object
// std::string doesn't define virtual destructor
```

Answer (score 5):

Implicit conversions are the devil, anyway.  Make it explicit with a converting function call.

Comment: Well, it depends. There are real situations where implicit conversions make sense. I typically use them, for example, to convert one type to another one which is, in semantic terms, a subset of the other. If you have an `person` class and an `employee`, for example, I would expect that `employee` automatically converts to `person` wherever the latter is expected. (Of course, implicitly converting the other way round would be a bad idea, on the other hand.)

Comment: I realize that you were just proposing a hypothetical example, but employee as a subclass of person is a bad design and a pet peeve of mine.

Subclassing is used for an is-a relationship. It seems that an employee is a person, but in fact that is just part of the ambiguity of English grammar. An employee is not a special type of person, but is instead a role that a person can have. It is actually a has-a relationship.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. What you could do as an alternative is to create a conversion constructor in the target class (not your case, as you want to convert to std::string - unless you derive it). But I agree to the other answers, I think an implicit conversion is not recommended in this case - especially because you're not converting from an object but from a pointer. Better to have a free function, your code will be easier to understand and the next programmer to inherit the code will for sure thank you.